`docker-compose up` command must spinup the database server, apply all required migrations and run the telegram bot application
To test that the work is done correctly, I would like torun the following commands:
export POSTGRES_PASSWORD=.....
export BOT_TOKEN=...
docker-compose up
docker-compose up command must spinup the database server, apply all required migrations and run the telegram bot application.
No other actions is expected to be executed to make the bot up and ready.
currently i am using a .env
but i want to use docker to get the inputs of POSTGRES_PASSWORD and BOT_TOKEN.
so the user can be able to use their customized bot token and postgres password
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: Telegram_Fliter_Bot

  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    environment:
      BOT_TOKEN: ${BOT_TOKEN}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    depends_on:
      - db

i previously tried to use the .env but i want to get the credentials from the user

It seems like that should work with the Compose file you show (you can omit the values of e.g. POSTGRES_PASSWORD: to pass through from the host's environment); is there a specific problem you're running into?
